# iOS error casting Object in Swift which inherited from an Obj-C Class

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

We've discovered a problem in our project when inheriting from an Objective C class in a Swift class

ViewController.m

```
@implementation ViewController

+ (ViewController*) getObj {
    ViewController *obj = [[SwiftController alloc] init];
    return obj;
}
```

SwiftController.swift

```
    class SwiftController: ViewController { }
```

When testing the code the following test fails

```
    class Test: XCTestCase {
        func testFails() {
            let obj = ViewController.getObj()
            XCTAssertTrue(obj is SwiftController)
        }
    }
```

---

Implementing the same behaviour in swift only works fine.

```
    class FirstController { }
    class SecondController: FirstController {
        static func getObj() -> FirstController {
            let obj: FirstController = SecondController()
            return obj
        }
    }

    func testOk() {
        let obj = SecondController.getObj()
        XCTAssertTrue(obj is SecondController)
    }
```

Is this a swift/obj-c bug or does anyone have a solution for this behavior?

A copy of this sample project can be found on github: https://github.com/edgeftq/inheritanceTest.git

Cheers,
Eddy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `+[ViewController getObj]` is returning an object of type:

```
InheritanceTest.SwiftController
```

Your unit tests are comparing it against the class

```
InheritanceTestTests.SwiftController
```

The two classes are different.

Remove `SwiftController.swift` from the target membership of your unit tests, then add `@testable import InheritanceTest` at the top of `Test.swift`.

This will give your unit tests access to the same `SwiftController` that's used by `ViewController.m`.